# Binding/concatenation of Text field value as object

Tags: jquery

```
var filters = {
    name : {
        regex : /^[A-Za-z]{3,}$/,
        error : 'Must be at least 3 characters long, and must only contain letters.'
    },
    pass : {
        regex : /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/,
        error : 'Must be at least 6 characters long, and contain at least one number, one uppercase and one lowercase letter.'
    },
    email : {
        regex : /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/,
        error : 'Must be a valid e-mail address (user@gmail.com)'
    },
    phone : {
        regex : /^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/,
        error : 'Must be a valid US phone number (999-999-9999)'
    }
};
```

I have filter as mention in above code. Now I want to retrieve object
value based on input field.  How can I bind that value to filter
object.

```
var Name = $("#NameField").val();
var type = $("#InputField").val();

if(filters.type.regex.test(Name))
{
 // My code
}
```

Here `type` can be text, email, etc.
I want to bind this value with filter.
How can I achieve this.
Or is there some other way to accomplish this ?

Comment: What does `bind this value` even mean? Not clear what you are asking

Comment: You have to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access the property of an object when the name is stored in a variable -> `filters[type].regex.test(Name)`